# What is the purpose of a swap button in an airline booking app?

Tags: usability, buttons, terminology

I am new to the community so I appreciate all replies :)

First, what is the official terminology for this type of button?

Second, what purpose does it serve in booking a flight?

[image: A flight booking screen with To and From fields, and a highlighted button in between them with an icon of two arrows pointing in opposite directions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to save the user time from having to re-input values.

I've heard it called a swap button, but that's informal.

This is a common pattern in applications where a trip is being planned (or en route). It allows users to quickly reverse the start and end destinations.

[image]

The *principle* behind it is more important to know: don't make users do more work than they need to.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I totally get the idea behind it in google maps. But what is the point of swapping the airports in a travel app?